# ruby regex to remove extra \n

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a mal-formatted `.csv` file which is caused by some extra `\n`. e.g.:

```
Name,Comment
"Peter","Good morning"
"Paul","How are you
"
"Mary","Fine"
```

The 2nd row ends with a unwanted, extra `\n`.

How can I remove all tailing `\n`s which are not followed by a double-quote `"` (assume the whole file is read into a string already)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't read the whole thing into a string, use the standard [CSV parser in 1.9](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html) to read it. If you have that in, say, `pancakes.csv`, then:

```
require 'csv'
data = CSV.open('pancakes.csv').map { |r| r.map(&:strip) }
# or
data = CSV.open('pancakes.csv').map { |r| r.map(&:chomp) }
```

Then you'll have this in `data`:

```
[
    ["Name", "Comment"],
    ["Peter", "Good morning"],
    ["Paul", "How are you"],
    ["Mary", "Fine"]
]
```

So you can get your data all clean and nicely parsed quite simply. And if you just need to clean up the CSV for some other program that can't handled embedded newlines, then you can use CSV to write it back out again.

Comment: For some reason I have to stay in 1.8.7 and use `fastercsv`. Is there similar in `fastercsv`? Thanks!

Comment: @ohho: AFAIK 1.9's `csv` is just `fastercsv` with some Unicode patches so it should work the same with `fastercsv` in 1.8.

Comment: it gives the same error as `FasterCSV.foreach`, i.e.: `FasterCSV::MalformedCSVError (FasterCSV::MalformedCSVError)`

Comment: I found that the error was not caused by the multi-line issue. The error only shows up in a `utf-8` file which was converted from a `utf-16 LE` file.

Comment: Further investigation reveals it's caused by extra double quotes `"`s: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887359/how-to-remove-the-extra-double-quote

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just add a trailing double quote for lines which don't end in a double quote, and remove empty lines (lines that only have a double quote)?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a Regexp for that.  It's basically any double-quote on its own line:

```
csv_string.gsub("\n\"\n", "\"\n")
```