# How to remove the extra double quote?

Tags: ruby, regex

In a malformed .csv file, there is a row of data with extra double quotes, e.g. the last line:

```
Name,Comment
"Peter","Nice singer"
"Paul","Love "folk" songs"
```

How can I remove the double quotes around `folk` and replace the string as:

```
Name,Comment
"Peter","Nice singer"
"Paul","Love _folk_ songs"
```

Answer (score 8):

In Ruby 1.9, the following works:

```
result = subject.gsub(/(?<!^|,)"(?!,|$)/, '_')
```

Previous versions don't have lookbehind assertions.

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!^|,)  # Assert that we're not at the start of the line or right after a comma
"         # Match a quote
(?!,|$)   # Assert that we're not at the end of the line or right before a comma
```

Of course this assumes that we won't run into pathological cases like

```
"Mary",""Oh," she said"
```

Comment: Based on his other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886051/), I'd say the chance of pathological cases is quite high.

Comment: Is there an version for ruby 1.8.7? Thanks!

Comment: No, because that feature is missing from Ruby versions < 1.9.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not on Ruby 1.9, or just get tired of regexes sometimes, split the string on `,`, strip the first/last quotes, replace remaining `"`s with `_`s, re-quote, and join with `,`.

(We don't *always* have to worry about efficiency!)

Comment: Yeah, until `"Peter, Paul and Mary","Puff, the Magic Dragon"` comes along :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker (Yeah, I had an internal struggle trying to remember if Ruby's CSV library would handle this right, so I finally punted on all of it.)

Comment: `fastercsv` cannot handle this (at least with default settings)

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '"folk"';

$new = str_replace('"', '', $str);

/* now $new is only folk, without " */
```

Comment: I can't decide if I should vote this up for humor, or down for kind of missing the point.

Answer (score 0):

Meta-strategy:

It's likely the case that the data was manually entered inconsistently, CSV's get messy when people manually enter either field terminators (double quote) or separators (comma) into the field itself.  If you can have the file regenerated, ask them to use an extremely unlikely field begin/end marker, like 5 tilde's (~~~~~), and then you can split on "~~~~~,~~~~~" and get the correct number of fields every time.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have no other choice, get the file regenerated with correct escaping. Any other approach is asking for trouble, because the insertion of unescaped quotes is lossy, and thus cannot be reliably reversed.

If you can't get the file fixed from the source, then Tim Pietzcker's regex is better than nothing, but I strongly recommend that you have your script print all "fixed" lines and check them for errors manually.