# How do I delete stray double-quotes in a CSV file before my code runs?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a CSV file I import from one site and export to another web app.

However, when running my Ruby file I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\ALilland\Documents\sinatra\csv_to_screen>ruby app.rb
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/csv.rb:1843:in `block (2 levels) in shift': Missing or
stray quote in line 762 (CSV::MalformedCSVError)
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/csv.rb:1836:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/csv.rb:1836:in `block in shift'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/csv.rb:1796:in `loop'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/csv.rb:1796:in `shift'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/csv.rb:1738:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/csv.rb:1122:in `block in foreach'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/csv.rb:1273:in `open'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/csv.rb:1121:in `foreach'
    from app.rb:129:in `lost'
    from app.rb:157:in `scorecard'
    from app.rb:203:in `<main>'
```

This is an example of where a quote does not need to be in my data `"GENERAL CONTRACTOR, ..."`:

```
MM,MM,"VENABLE, LLP","LOS ANGELES","GENERAL CONTRACTOR, ...",,Dead,02/11/2016,0
```

This is an example of completely missing quotes on `irvine`:

```
GS,GS,"REPLACE 1.5 DIELECTRIC UNION,IRVINE,"THE IRVINE CO. -  EXECU...",,Job162048,02/01/2016,0
```

These "missing or stray quotes" are scattered throughout the CSV, usually in `project_name = row[2]`.

What can I do to overwrite the stray quotes before my `foreach` block runs?

Here is a post I found that relates to my problem, but I was struggling to figure out how to implement it. This error seems rather well documented on the internet, I even heard a podcast on it the other day but now I officially ran into the problem firsthand and have come up empty. "[How to remove the extra double quote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887359/how-to-remove-the-extra-double-quote)"

My complete `foreach` block is:

```
def lost(initials, salesperson)
  my_status = 'Lost'
  lost = 0
  count = 0
  CSV.foreach(path1, :encoding => 'windows-1251:utf-8') do |row|
    salesman = row[0]
    project_manager = row[1]
    project_name = row[2]
    project_city = row[3]
    customer = row[4]
    status = row[6]
    if status[0,4] == 'Dead'
      status = 'Dead'
    end
    bid_date = Date.strptime(row[7], '%m/%d/%Y')
    amount = row[8].gsub(/(?<!^|,)"(?!,|$)/, '').tr(',', '').to_i

    next if salesman != initials || status != my_status || bid_date < fiscal_start
    dollar_amount = '$' + amount.to_s.reverse.gsub(/...(?=.)/,'\&,').reverse
    lost = lost + amount
    count = count + 1
  end
   @lost_count = count.to_s
   @lost_amount = "$" + lost.to_s.reverse.gsub(/...(?=.)/,'\&,').reverse
end
```

Comment: Get your co-worker to fix his app so it generates valid .csv (I know this may be easier said than done, but any other fixes might cause your code to break if it ever has to process correct .csv)

Comment: Also, post an example of the problematic .csv file

Comment: the app was made 8 years ago by another programmer in PHP, that programmer was fired long ago :(, we have since begun working on a new rewrite, completely abandoning the old and it will be done in feb 2017, unfortunately its still very much in use and using the data in excel got old. im writing up a tool in sinatra to display reports for the next year when our new app is finished

Comment: You won't be able to parse it with CSV then; you'll have to read it in as text and try to do the parsing yourself (although from the examples you gave, that seems like it will be quite a task)-- Does Excel in fact read it correctly?

Comment: yeah, excel is able to read it just fine

Comment: You can either use Excel to correct the problem, which Ruby could script, or use Ruby solely to open, split the lines on commas which is very error-prone, then rebuild them using CSV. When processing data problems it takes a lot of domain knowledge to fix the problem. CSV is especially prone to incorrect generation because people assume they understand the spec and then the corner-cases pop up that the code butchers.

Comment: for my excel option i would essentially programatically just open and save the CSV  and read the new csv?